# How do I avoid focus highlighting in touch mode?

Tags: android, focus

I'm trying to make my app friendly for keyboard driven navigation and I've added a focus highlight around all actionable items. I'm having trouble removing the focus highlighting when operating in touch mode. In other words, I don't want the focus highlighting to be visible when not using keyboard navigation. Is this possible? I'm experimenting with several variations of item states in my selector XML as well as toying with different values of focusableInTouchMode but I'm not getting anywhere. I have an EditText defined as follows:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:background="@drawable/edit_text_selector"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

and I have its selctor defined here (with many of the state permutations commented out):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">    
    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <layer-list>
            <item android:drawable="@drawable/focusbox"/>
            <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
                <corners android:radius="8dp" />
                <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#044401" />
                <solid android:color="@color/edit_text_color" />
            </shape>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
<!--     <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_activated="false">
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="8dp" />
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#044400" />
            <solid android:color="@color/edit_text_color" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true">
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="8dp" />
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#044400" />
            <solid android:color="@color/edit_text_color" />
        </shape>
    </item>
 -->    <item android:state_focused="false">
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="8dp" />
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#044400" />
            <solid android:color="@color/edit_text_color" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

The only idea I've come up with from what I've learned is that I can detect if a view is in touch mode programmatically and use this to decide wether or not to show the focus highlighting. I currently have a XML drawable that draws a box for focus which I could recode in Java as a custom drawable but the problem is that a drawable cannot query for touch mode nor does it have access to its view. Are there any other options?

Comment: i dont understand why you want to query touch mode - there is no focus highlighting in touch mode

Comment: I can query for touch mode using View.isInTouchMode(). My problem is that my custom focus ring applied using the above selector draws when I'm in touch mode, thus highlighting the focused item.

Comment: i always thought there is no selection nor focus in touch mode: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2008/12/touch-mode.html - quote "In touch mode, there is no focus and no selection."

Comment: I only wish that were true. Defining a custom drawable for when a view is focused seems to behave differently, or maybe I'm mis-using the API? At any rate, it's incredibly difficult for me to get this right.

Comment: I believe (from my observations, though I'm not 100% certain) the "no focus in touch mode" rule only applies to focus when accessibility is enabled. Assigning a custom drawable on item state focus seems to apply wether or not you're in touch mode.

Comment: To test it i would write a class that extends StateListDrawable and override its onStateChanged by logging StateSet.dump(newState)